# Python: arguments - 4 arguments allowed, 5 given

Tags: python, matrix

Trying to create a matrix to start a search algorithm.

```
from numpy import *

z11 = vars()
z12 = vars()
z13 = vars()
z14 = vars()
z21 = vars()
z22 = vars()
z23 = vars()
z24 = vars()
z31 = vars()
z32 = vars()
z33 = vars()
z34 = vars()
z41 = vars()
z42 = vars()
z43 = vars()
z44 = vars()

A = matrix([z11,z12,z13,z14], [z21,z22,z23,z24], [z31,z32,z33,z34], [z41,z42,z43,z44])
```

When it is run for errors, it comes up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Fusion Puzzle Algorithm 2.py", line 20, in <module>
    A = matrix([z11,z12,z13,z14], [z21,z22,z23,z24], [z31,z32,z33,z34], [z41,z42,z43,z44])
TypeError: __new__() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Look at what `matrix` expects its arguments to be: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your use case is, but it's always easier to replace repetitive statements with loops.  For example, you *explicitly* write out 16 variable names even though the names aren't really important.  Instead, place them directly into (nested) lists using `for` loops

```
variables = []
for row in range(4):
    row_variables = []
    for col in range(4):
        row_variables.append(vars())
    variables.append(row_variables)
A = matrix(variables)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
variables = [[vars() for col in range(4)] for row in range(4)]
A = matrix(variables)
```

Or even:

```
variables = [[vars()] * 4 for row in range(4)]
A = matrix(variables)
```

Answer (score 7):

You likely want something like:

```
A = matrix([[z11,z12,z13,z14], [z21,z22,z23,z24], [z31,z32,z33,z34], [z41,z42,z43,z44]])
```

Note that there is only one argument to the matrix constructor.

Comment: A tuple will work too A = matrix(([z11,z12,z13,z14], [z21,z22,z23,z24], [z31,z32,z33,z34], [z41,z42,z43,z44]))